# Reactjs login using Fetch with Spring rest

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I have created a working backend web service api using Spring tested on Postman.

**Spring controller method :**

```
@CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public ServiceResponse userLogin(@RequestBody User loginUser) {

        User checkLogin= repository.findByEmail(loginUser.getEmail());

        if(checkLogin!=null) {
            System.out.println("User Exists");
            //Checking password
            if(checkLogin.getPassword().equals(loginUser.getPassword()))
                return ServiceResponse.createSuccessResponse();
            else
                return ServiceResponse.createFailureResponse("Invalid Password Entry. Please try again.");
        }
        else {
                return ServiceResponse.createFailureResponse("User email does not exists!");
        }

    }
```

And using ReactJS I am displaying response sent back from service.

ReactJS Implementation:

```
constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            email:'',
            password:''
        }
    }

    handleEmail(text){
        this.setState({email:text.target.value})
    }
    handlePassword(text){
        this.setState({password:text.target.value})
    }

    login(){
        let obj={}
        obj.email=this.state.email;
        obj.password=this.state.password;

        fetch('http://localhost/login',
        {
            header:{
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            method:'POST',
            type:"cors",
            body:JSON.stringify({obj})

        }
        ).then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
        .then(function(data){ console.log( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })

    }

 render() {

        return (

       //User interface design for login implemented

);
}
```

But I am receiving

> Cannot POST /

as Error page title in a blank new page. Sometimes I receive an alert says **Unsupported media type**

Maybe in fetch service I might made some mistake. Anyone please point out or correct me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From the above react code i can see you didn't mention port number for your BackEnd Api. It should be like `fetch('http://localhost:portNo/login',{})`.

Comment: I added it didn't work then removed again. Please check something I might be missing that's the reason I am getting alert for Unsupported media type

Comment: Can you check if you can hit that endpoint with postman ? And also remove curly braces from JSON.Stringify(obj) , simply it doesnot makes any sense.

Comment: In question I have mentioned my endpoints are working. Though I was reading something about @RequestBody annotations actually it takes parameter. I was passing object then converting this object into json object rather I will send it as body:JSON.stringify({'email':this.state.email, 'password':this.state.password }) but it still not working :(

Comment: Hi I have changed it and now using axios library instead of fetch but I found one thing that email and password are going null even when I print it in console in login method at frontend then also

Comment: For updating a state use `this.setState({})` function.

Comment: using fetch and axios I did it with both. The changes is in getting response and converting in response.json() and also header should headers with extra 's' at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
handleUserChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      username: event.target.value,
    });
};



<input type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUserChange} />
```

Comment: `import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom' ` . `return <Redirect to='/successLogin'  />` .  and in route `<Route path="/loginSuccess" exact component={LoginSuccessComponent}></Route>`

Comment: `handleSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); //now call api and and handle success or failure
}`  Try something onSubmit event of your form.

Comment: Yes in new code I did it and is needed because reactjs is doing global refresh on change for submitting form....that is why I was taken to the next page

Comment: I am not able to understand your above comment completely, are you now able to overcome your error ??

Comment: yes that is what I am telling it worked and problem was I was missing this code in fetch method `.then(res=>res.json())`

Answer (score 0):

**Using fetch method:**

Note: fetch is a default method comes with various OPTIONS.

```
 return fetch('http://localhost:6020/login',
       {
           headers:{  
               "Accept": "application/json",
               "Content-Type": "application/json"
           },
           method:'POST',
           body:JSON.stringify(user)
       }
       ).then(response => response.json()) // this line is important
       .then((response) => { 

           console.log( JSON.stringify( response ));

        });
```

**Using axios library:**

```
axios.post('http://localhost:6020/login', user)
          .then(res=>{
              console.log(res);
              console.log(res.data);
          });
```